# Group by and Count on List

Tags: c#

I have a list of model class with some fields in it,I want to apply group by and count on the base of ID on it,in my lst I have data like this

```
lst[0]=Id=10,Name="user1",Gender="Male",Course="course1";
lst[1]=Id=10,Name="user1",Gender="Male",Course="course2";
lst[2]=Id=10,Name="user1",Gender="Male",Course="course3";
lst[3]=Id=11,Name="user2",Gender="Male",Course="course4";
```

I want to count the course with group by on Id.
This is how I am doing

```
var result = lst.GroupBy(n => n.Id).Select(c => new { Key = c.Key, total = c.Count()});
```

But after applying this I am not getting any value in result variable(ie result.Name or result[0].Name)
How can I apply group by and count in this list so I get the list data after applying the group by too.

Comment: You should call `ToList` or `ToArray` at the end of your statement to enfore the immediate execution of the query.

Comment: What *do* you get? Can you add the code to create a `lst`?

Comment: @HimBromBeere I have tried using this too,let me check with ToArray

Comment: @PatrickHofman I am generating list with datatable,which is result of Linq join among multiple tables

Comment: For me this perfectly works when calling `ToList`. Returns two elements: `Id = 10, Total = 3` and `ID = 11, Total = 1`.

Comment: I am getting only Key and total if I write result.ToList();

Comment: @HimBromBeere Yes thats what I am getting too,but I want other elements too

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Having used `GroupBy` you have projected (`Select(..)`) to an anonymous object which throws away the selected items in the group; your result will be an `IEnumerable<anonymous>` of items with properties `Key` and `total`

```
var result = lst.GroupBy(n => n.Id)
                .Select(c => new { Key = c.Key, total = c.Count()});
```

If you want to keep the selected items, you need to include this in your projection

```
var result = lst.GroupBy(n => n.Id)
                .Select(c => new { Key = c.Key, total = c.Count(), Items = c});
foreach(var r in result)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Key: {0} Count:{1}",r.Key,r.total)
    foreach(var i in r.Items)
        Console.WriteLine(i.Name);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The reason is because you are grouping by `Id` and just provinding an anonymous object with `Key` (which is the `Id`) and a `Count`. If you want to read the values, each item of the result group set will have the Count and the values where you can loop between them. For sample:

```
var result = lst.GroupBy(n => n.Id);

foreach (var g in result)
{
    Console.WriteLine("For group {0} the total is {1}.", g.Key, g.Count());
    foreach(var item in g)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Name: {0}", item.Name);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

All you have to do is call `ToList` or `ToArray`.

```
var result = lst.GroupBy(n => n.Id)
    .Select(c => new 
    { 
        Key = c.Key, 
        total = c.Count(),
        Gender = c.First().Gender
    }).ToList();
```

Or alternativly - to avoid multiple iterations of the same enumeration:

```
var result = lst.GroupBy(n => n.Id)
    .Select(c => 
    { 
        var firstEl = c.First();
        return new {
            Key = c.Key, 
            total = c.Count(),
            Gender = firstEl.Gender,
            Name = firstEl.Name,
            Course = firstEl.Course
        }
    }).ToList();
```

`Select` will only return a query which is [deferredly executed](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/bb943859.aspx). This means you get the result when you actually iterate on the enumeration, which is enforeced by calling one of the mentioned methods.

Comment: Yes thats what I am getting too,but I want other elements too in my result variable

Comment: Adding `ToList()` \ `ToArray()` will not magic back the items which have been thrown away from the `IGrouping`

Comment: Name, Gender and course which I have in original list